# Using the .shadow modifier on a SwiftUI View that sits above a scrollview, a visible shadow line can be seen when other views overlap

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

On the bottom of my app I have a rectangle that contains a button (both in the foreground). I then have another rectangle below it that's half the height so I can add a shadow modifier on it. Underneath that is a scrollview, which contains a set of views that are generated using ForEach.

[image: Shadow]

The shadow works great when there are no ForEach views underneath it, and the shadow code isn't anything fancy.

```
ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .top)) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: Color("LightDarkModeShadow"), radius: 20, x: 0, y: -5)
                    .opacity(0.33)
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 110)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("LightDarkModeBackground"))
```

However, when the scrollview contains entries and they're underneath the shadow, a line is visible overtop the view. It seems like it doesn't blend properly. Is there any way to fix this, or is this just by design?

[image: Shadow Line]

Comment: Set foregroundColor(.clear) to shadow rectangle

Comment: @RajaKishan I just tried your suggestion, unfortunately when I set the .foregroundColor(.clear) on the shadow rectangle it causes the shadow to disappear completely.

Comment: Hmm set Zindex 1 to ForEach view or your view which is not visible

Comment: Also why used another rectangle for shadow? Is it not set with one rectangle?

Comment: Setting the Zindex to 1 doesn't work either, just tried it. I'm using another rectangle for the shadow so I can make the shadow only come out of the top. I tried putting the shadow on the big rectangle that contains the button but it makes the shadow come from every side which I don't want.

Comment: Setting the Zindex to 1 To scroll view?

Comment: @vidvi You could probably make this work with a shadow, but if you only want this on one edge, you could use `LinearGradient` transitioning from black with some opacity to black with 0 opacity. Just place this bottom view and the shadow in a `VStack` and that should work.

Comment: Else set -1 zindex to ZStack

Comment: @RajaKishan Yep, I tried setting the Zindex to 1 on the scrollview and it didn't fix it. Nothing changed.

Comment: Is your scroll view and bottom view is under VStack ? If yes then give minus bottom padding to scroll view with zindex 1

Comment: @George_E I'm having a hard time visualizing what you mean, but I'm willing to try it.

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes everything is enclosed in a VStack. I've tried all your zIndex suggestions and they aren't working unfortunately. Wish they did.

Comment: @RajaKishan Managed to fix it! Check my answer. No zIndex necessary :).

Comment: I mentioned it to set bottom padding to minus.

Comment: @RajaKishan Yeah I know, I thanked you in the answer :).

Comment: Yes I checked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RajaKishan in the comments for pointing me in the right direction. The scrollview had .padding(.bottom) applied to it. I think it was butted up against the rectangle shadow and created a line. I added a negative padding value to the scrollview:

```
.padding(.bottom, -10)
```

The issue is now gone!

[image: Fixed]